# Redis-cli --cluster create command is not working?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, redis, redis-sentinel

I have redis-server package through standard apt command, but when I'm trying to run redis-cli --cluster create its not working. I'm getting "Unrecognized option or bad number of args for: '--cluster'". Please help me to fix it.

Comment: Where is the rest of the command line arguments?

Comment: redis-cli --cluster create 172.16.121.118:6379 172.16.121.125:6379 172.16.121.234:6379 172.16.121.125:6381 172.16.121.234:6381 172.16.121.118:6381 --cluster-replicas 1